# C# Rich text box highlight

Tags: c#, richtextbox, highlight

I have a rich text box and a font dialog box. The problem is that when i highlight a certain string or group of strings then open the dialog box, the highlight color disappears. Although the changes are successful (like if i change the font family of a highlighted string it changes). For aesthetic purposes i would like to retain the highlight color, then remove it whenever the changes are done.

THANK YOU for the help!

Answer (score 5):

The rich text box has a property called `HideSelection` which is true by default. That causes the highlight to disappear when the text box loses focus (as it does when you open the font dialog).

Setting `HideSelection` to false should cause the highlight to remain.

RichTextBox inherits this property from TextBoxBase:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.hideselection.aspx