# Preserve highlight in RichTextBox when focus changes to a dialog?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox

I'm using WPF, .NET4, VS2010.

I have a RichTextBox that I'm letting the user edit in. I have implemented a Find/Replace dialog. The user puts in a Find string and a Replace string. When they click on Replace, it searches in the RTB for the next occurence of the Find string and selects (highlights) it. If the user clicks Replace again, it replaces the text and searches again, selecting(highlighting) the next occurence.

The problem is, the user cannot see the highlighting in the RichTextBox. I have found solutions for how to preserve the highlighting when the RTB loses focus - notably, handling `OnLostFocus` and setting `e.Handled` to `true`. But, this only seems to work when focus is going to another control on the same WPF form. In my case, I have a separate WPF form (my Find/Replace dialog). When focus returns to that, the highlight of the selected text in the RTB disappears - though when I close my Find/Replace dialog and focus returns to the main form, the selected text is highlighted appropriately.

I have tried this using `ShowDialog()` to display my Find/Replace dialog and also using `Show()`.

So, the question is, is there a way to have my RTB show the selected text even when focus is on my Find/Replace dialog?

Comment: you can try this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848470/c-sharp-rich-text-box-highlight

Comment: Thanks, but the WPF version of RichTextBox does not have the HideSelection property. I believe the WPF TextBox does not, either. Both of those controls have those properites in WinForms, though, I think.

Comment: One way to solve this problem is to use Adorners for the highlighting, rather than selections.  In our project you can see how we handled highlighting.

https://github.com/keyoti/RapidFindReplaceWPF/tree/master/Keyoti.RapidFindReplaceControl/FindHandlers/HighlightHandlers